# LinkedListNode after add to LinkedList doesn't set next and previous fields

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and am trying to use `LinkedList<T>`

```
class News {
    private int Id { get; set; }
    private string Name { get; set; }

    public News (int id, string name) {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public string getName() {
        return Name;
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var newsList = new LinkedList<LinkedListNode<News>>();

        newsList.AddLast(new LinkedListNode<News>(new News(1,"News first")));
        newsList.AddLast(new LinkedListNode<News>(new News(2, "News second")));
        newsList.AddLast(new LinkedListNode<News>(new News(3, "News third")));
    }
}
```

Once the above code runs, I wind up with `newsList` containing 3 nodes, where `node.Previous` and `node.Next` are both `null`. What am I doing wrong?

========================================= my actual code =========================

```
public ActionResult NewsDetail(int id = 0)
        {

            var an = db.News
                .Select(n => new NewsView
                {
                    Id = n.Id,
                    Name = n.Name,
                    Description = n.Description,
                    IsTop = n.IsTop,
                    IsDraft = n.IsDraft,
                    Content = n.Content,
                    CaruselContentType = n.CaruselContentType,
                    CaruselFileContent = n.CaruselFileContent,
                    CaruselFileName = n.CaruselFileName,
                    CaruselFileSize = n.CaruselFileSize,

                    NewsPartViews = n.NewsParts
                    .Select(
                       np => new NewsPartView
                       {
                           Id = np.Id,
                           SortNumber = np.SortNumber,
                           IsDraft = np.IsDraft,
                           Content = np.Content,
                           NewsId = np.NewsId,
                           NewsPartImagesPosition = np.NewsPartImagesPosition,
                           ImagesCols = np.ImagesCols,
                           ImagesWidth = np.ImagesWidth,
                           ImagesHeight = np.ImagesHeight,
                           ImagesBorder = np.ImagesBorder,
                           ImagesClickEnlarge = np.ImagesClickEnlarge,
                           NewsPartImageViews = np.NewsPartImages
                           .Select(
                           npi => new NewsPartImageView
                           {
                               Id = npi.Id
                           }
                           )
                       }
                    )
                });


            var newslList = new LinkedList<NewsView>(an);




            return View(newslList.Find(newslList.First(view => view.Id == id)));
        }
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're doing with the linked list and why that's not working.  Please show the actual code you're using and explain either the errors you're getting, or how the behavior is different from your expectations.

Comment: now working fine, added actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your LinkedListNode objects have only one item each; according to the MSDN documentation,

LinkedListNode.Previous Property: A reference to the previous node in the LinkedList, **or null** if the current node is the first element (First) of the LinkedList.

LinkedListNode.Next Property: A reference to the next node in the LinkedList, **or null** if the current node is the last element (Last) of the LinkedList.

If there's only one element, it is both the first and the last - thus you'll get NULL results for both methods.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't have a `LinkedList<LinkedListNode<News>>`.  You should be using a `LinkedList<News>`.  The `LinkedList` will implicitly be wrapping each element in it's own `LinkedListNode`.  What's happening for you is that there's a bunch of `LinkedListNode<LinkedListNode<News>>` objects, and the `Next`/`Previous` of the outer nodes are all set appropriately, but your inner nodes all have `null` for the `Next`/`Previous` properties.

Here is an appropriate method of creating the `LinkedList`.

```
var newsList = new LinkedList<News>();

newsList.AddLast(new News(1,"News first"));
newsList.AddLast(new News(2, "News second"));
newsList.AddLast(new News(3, "News third"));
```

Also note that `LinkedList` is usually not the best data structure to use; it's rarely preferable to another type of collection.  Odds are you're better off using either a `List`, `Stack`, a `Queue`, depending on what you're doing with it.

Answer (score 1):

When using a linkedlist the type T does not need to be a LinkedListNode of the desired type. You can use the desired type directly.

```
 var newsList = new LinkedList<News>();

 newsList.AddLast(new LinkedListNode<News>(new News(1, "News first")));
 newsList.AddLast(new LinkedListNode<News>(new News(2, "News second")));
 newsList.AddLast(new LinkedListNode<News>(new News(3, "News third")));
```

This will setup your linked list the way you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add all the three items to the list, use this,

```
var newsItems = new News[]  {
           new News(1,"News first"), 
           new News(2, "News second"), 
           new News(3, "News third")};

var newsList = new LinkedList<News>(newsItems);
```